# why the value inside the foreach repeated twice

Tags: php, loops, foreach, while-loop

i'm wondering why the value inside foreach repeated twice ?
i put foreach inside a while loop. but the while loop condition turn to false and still repeated the value inside the foreach

```
<?php
       `$conn = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','capstone_prac_db');

       $sql1 = "SELECT id FROM stocks ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1,1";
       $result1 = mysqli_query($conn,$sql1);

  ?>
   <!DOCTYPE html>
   <html>
   <head>
     <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
       <?php
           while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result1)){
               foreach ($row as $value) {
                    echo $value;
              }
           }
       ?>
   </body>
   </html>
```

Comment: Odds are your while loop is running more than once... it should run once for each row that your query returns

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php

         `$conn = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','capstone_prac_db');

   $sql1 = "SELECT id FROM stocks ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1,1";
       $result1 = mysqli_query($conn,$sql1);

  ?>
   <!DOCTYPE html>
   <html>
   <head>
     <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
       <?php
       $i=0;
           while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result1)){

                    echo $row[$i];
                    $i++;

           }
       ?>
   </body>
   </html>
```

You have 2 loops one nested another one. Try the code above.

Comment: Depends sometimes it is necessary , sometimes it is over-kill and sometimes it is just wrong. In here it is wrong according to what you expect as output.

Comment: If my answer , answers your question please accept it.

Comment: Sorry i'm new here, i don't know how to do that.

Comment: Press the star under the voting arrows of my answer if answered your question.

Answer (score 0):

See docs for [`mysqli_fetch_array()`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-array.php) and note the second argument defaults to `MYSQLI_BOTH`. This means the array that you're iterating consists of a single record, but indexed both numerically and associatively. So you're iterating over two array indexes that both point to the same value.

```
$row[0];
$row['id'];
```

To correct, call the function like this:

```
mysqli_fetch_array($result1, MYSQLI_ASSOC)
```

Answer (score 0):

mysqli::fetch_array returns all rows as an array. The while loop is usually used with [fetch_row](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-row.php), where it'll loop through all the rows and perform the looped actions on each one separately.

Rather than using both types of loop, pick one and run with it. You can use

```
$result = mysqli_fetch_array($result1);
foreach($result1 as $value){
    //Do your stuff here
}
```

or

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_row($result)){
    //Do stuff here
}
```

Bear in mind that [query](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php) returns a [mysqli::result](http://php.net/manual/en/class.mysqli-result.php) object, and not an array directly. You'll have to use one of the methods listed on the results docs page to get usable data out of the object.